# Situation when queue manager is unable to add item to re-execution?

Tags: php, queue

Let's imagine that we're executing some tasks in queue. When executing some queue item we're catching some exception and trying to add this item back to queue for retry, but `QueueManager` is unable to do it because of lost connection with Redis (for example) or any other problem.

```
$Item = $QueueManager->getNext();
try {
    $Item->runWorker();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $Item->incrementRetries();
    $QueueManager->addItem($Item); //what to do if error occures here?
}
```

As you can see, we're loosing item.
What to do in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by connection lost, it's an intermittent problem, I would attempt to reconnect.  If that still fails, or it's the case of an outage, then you either build redundancy in the infrastructure, or handle redundancy in your code.

You can increase the availability of your queue/db.  Set up a load balancer and multiple nodes (either independent or replicating).  If one goes down, it would fail over to a working one.   Depending on the software you are using for the queue, it might persist all jobs to disk so if it goes down, the jobs can still be processed when it comes back online.  You just need ensure at least one node is always running and accepting connections. Depending on the queue you are using thought, this may or may not be possible.

If additional hardware isn't an option then you will need to handle it in your code.  You will need to add alternate fallbacks.  You could use a fallback database and insert the data into there, or write the data for a flat file, and process that later once connections are restored.  If you are using multiple servers, a fallback that stores the data locally on each server might be problematic though.

I'm not sure what software you are using for the queue (I assume you are using Redis since you mentioned it) but check if there is a method that doesn't remove the item from the queue until you tell it.  That way if you lose connection and the item fails, you don't need to re-add it to the queue since it's still there, you just need to maybe set a timeout and move on.  The item will then be re-tried at some point down the line.  If the item was processed, and you still have a connection, you then remove it from the queue, and move on.

Lastly, maybe you need to evaluate whether the current software you are using for the queue is the right choice for you.  Maybe you need to find one with higher reliability and/or supports a similar use case as I mentioned above.

Hope that helps

Comment: I really appreciate your extended explanation! Thank you very much.